# How to align text in the middle in ul li?

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the below drop down menu that the text is not aligned in the middle although I have used text-align: center and vertical-align: middle property as well, but it's not working. The text is horizontally aligned in the center, but it's not vertically aligned in the middle.

```css
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #999;
}

a:hover {
  color: #777;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #95C11F;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation,
.navigation a.main {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.navigation:hover,
.navigation:hover a.main {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.navigation a.main {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 41px;
  height: 50px;
  font: bold 20px/40px calibri, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation:hover a.main {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.navigation li {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  font: normal 12px/40px arial, sans-serif !important;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 1px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.navigation li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

.navigation li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

.navigation li.n1 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n2 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n3 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n4 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n5 {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover li {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover .n2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.navigation:hover .n3 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.navigation:hover .n4 {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.navigation:hover .n5 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown-style.css">
    <a class="main" href="#url">BUY NOW</a>
    <li class="n1"><a href="#url">BUY ON AMAZON US</a></li>
    <li class="n2"><a href="#url">BUY ON AMAZON CA</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Kindly let me know what changes shall I make to align the text vertically in the middle?

TIA!

Comment: You don't need any of those vendor prefixes in the modern web. See https://caniuse.com/transforms2d, for example.

Comment: Also, your list structure is invalid. Link and anchor elements are not allowed as children of a list element.

Comment: @isherwood I have used "text-align: center;" and "vertical-align: middle;"

Comment: So update your post to say that. It says something else at the moment. :)

Comment: @TaimoorAhmed Use `line-height` equal to the height of your box height, it will automatically put the text in the center of the box. In example it is `line-height:50px`. Give it a try. And Enjoy. Asalamu,Alykum :)

Comment: Don't use line-height on your `a` to achieve a certain height. Use `text-align: center;` on navigation and use padding instead. [***See here***](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/db5n17os/1/)

Comment: @Kameron Hi! We use it were ever required. Why do you suggest padding though. Wouldn't padding increase the height of the box if not taken care by `box-sizing:border-box` property and handling the padding to center the text vertically is not achieved by `text-aligh:center;` :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather you have a point if it is equal to the box height. However, in this example, it was not so I didn't suggest it. IMO padding is a better solution to achieve a specific height and width of a certain element when the children are already centered. He has too many different heights going on.

Comment: @Kameron thanks, your solution partially worked. It worked on the BUY NOW button but as you hover over it, you can see that hover color-shade isn't all over the button now.  And rest of the list items are not aligned with the BUY NOW button. I'd be pleased if you could somehow resolve this issue.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather thanks, I tried the line-height: 50px, but it didn't work. Please suggest if I have to make some more changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  color: #999;
}

a:hover {
  color: #777;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: #95C11F;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.navigation,
.navigation a.main {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.navigation:hover,
.navigation:hover a.main {
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}

.navigation a.main {
  font: bold 20px/40px calibri, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation:hover a.main {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.navigation li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  font: normal 12px/40px arial, sans-serif !important;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 1px auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.navigation li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

.navigation li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

.navigation li.n1 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n2 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n3 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n4 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n5 {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover li {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.1s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover .n2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.navigation:hover .n3 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.navigation:hover .n4 {
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.navigation:hover .n5 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

The above CSS should sort out your issues. Apply it in the sandbox or check it [in my codepen](https://codepen.io/arkadiusz71/pen/RwLLpOQ?editors=1100) before you copy/paste. You're breaking "good code" rules as mentioned in the comments under your question. I decided to skip that and simply deliver an answer based on existing HTML.

Comment: You mean to say in my current code I have to paste .n1 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
} for every n1, n2 and n3??

Comment: I've edited my answer, sorry for a previous, hasty reply, was in a rush and thought it will be enough to help you.

Comment: thanks man! now it really looks exactly how I wanted. Could you please tell me what major change did you do in the code?

Comment: I removed `height: 100%` from `a`, also removed `display`, `vertical-align`, `line-height` and `height` from `navigation a.main` selector and added `padding: 5px 0` to it and this soted out the main button, then I added `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to `.navigation li` to center the text in appearing buttons.

Comment: great, thanks again!! It was very helpful...